# Контроль курсора при вводе текста в консоли

Tags: python

Пишу одну программу, в которой от пользователя требуется периодически вводить данные.
При вводе в консоли, при попытке вернуться назад/вперед по тексту (блин, ну не знаю как объяснить, нажимая например стрелки на клаве) вводиться какая-то фигня вроде "^[[D". Как от этого избавится и дать пользователю возможность вводить текст нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотреть это модуль: [readline](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html). Потом разобрать [пример](http://effbot.org/librarybook/readline.htm). И тут [почитать](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/readline/index.html).